# Java : how to get correct result?

Tags: java, math, double

In java:

```
double b = 1234 / (1234+1500);
```

result is:

```
0.0
```

why?

How to get correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make one of the operand `double`/`float` -

```
double b = (double) 1234.0/(1235+1500);
```

Here casting is not required.

The **rules benind**: if one of the operand is `double`/`float` (here 1234.0) the other is promoted to `double`/`float`.

Answer (score 1):

```
double b = 1234D / (1234D + 1500D)
```

Comment: but i am using an local variable to give input value... how to implement it

Comment: I only answered your original question. To be honest, I would not use doubles for arithmetic. Use BigDecimals and parse your inputs to them

Answer (score 0):

You get `0.0` because java will be an integer devision. To get the correct result you have to cast at least on operator to `double`.

```
double b = ((double)1234) / (1234+1500)
```

Comment: @VigneshRajendran if it works feel free to accept and/or upvote my answer.